# How to mark a .desktop file as trusted from command line on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: permissions, .desktop

I tried:

```
gio set myapp.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes
```

and

```
dbus-launch gio set myapp.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes
```

and get from both:

```
gio: Setting attribute metadata::trusted not supported
```

Comment: I was curious to learn where this data gets stored. It turns out, file attributes end up being stored in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add execution bit for the desktop file:

```
cd ~/Desktop
chmod a+x myapp.desktop
```

and mark it as trusted with

```
gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted yes
```

and then press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the desktop icons.

Comment: I am still having the same message gio: Setting attribute metadata::trusted not supported.

Comment: I do not have any problem on ext4 filesystem if this matters.

Comment: @VitorAbella try `dbus-launch gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted yes` or if you ar eusing Ubuntu-20 `dbus-launch gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted true`

Comment: Additionally, if this is scripted and run as root: `sudo -u youruser -g youruser dbus-launch gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted true`. Then check for success: `sudo -u youruser -g youruser dbus-launch gio info myapp.desktop | grep trusted`

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue in UBUNTU 20.04LTS today and I noticed that the value yes has been replaced by true

so in case tou are searching for ubuntu 20.04 and you come in this link use the following  command:

```
gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running as root user, run the below command to set the metadata

```
sudo -u <username> -g <username> dbus-launch gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted yes
```