# How to make a starter "launchable" via a command line on Ubuntu 20.04.x and Gnome?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome, launcher, debian

I'll try to describe below ***exactly*** what I'm looking to do below:

On Ubuntu 20.04.x with the new version of Gnome, when you create a launcher on the desktop (via a script for example), you have to make this starter "launchable".

The manipulation proposed on the right and on the left everywhere on the web is, **only via the graphical interface**, to make a right click on the icon of the launcher, then to select the "Allow launching" option.

[image: Allow launching]

and voila!

But what I'm looking for precisely and only is: ***what is the Linux command that the Gnome GUI executes to make that launchable launcher?***

In the same way, for example, that the graphical interface makes it possible to make an executable file by checking the option "*Allow executing file as a program*" of the dialog panel Properties/Permissions of a launcher... which corresponds to the command ***chmod + x***.

[image: Allow executing file as a program]

Despite all my laborious and extensive research, I can't find any documentation on this subject although I don't think it's a state secret and of course there must be a command line for it.

I hope I have been clear enough in my explanation.

Anyway, thank you in advance for any help in this regard.

Best regards.

PS: From memory, with Gnome under the latest versions of Debian, the term is "Trustable" instead of "Launchable". I guess the command should then be similar, if not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mark a .desktop file as trusted from command line on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202488/how-to-mark-a-desktop-file-as-trusted-from-command-line-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thanks to "nobody", the command ~ gio set /location_of_the_starter/name_of_the_starter metadata::trusted yes #true for Ubuntu