# Starting an appimage

Tags: alias, functions

This may seem like a simple question but I am attempting to create a function in my .bash_aliases that would chmod the appimage as executable then start the appimage.
The function that I have written seems to not do what I'm expecting, any help is appreciated, here is the function used.

```shell
    function initai
{

    chmod a+x $1
    gio set $1 metadata::trusted true
    $1
}
```

update 1 : The usb was mounted with Nemo(under nemo is states usb drive is msdos and findmnt states the filesystem is vfat) mount location is /dev/sda1

update 2 : the output of `cat /proc/mounts` is:

```shell
/dev/sda1 /media/chico/USB20FD vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Comment: What is the error output? Why do out need a script instead of just doing this once?

Comment: I am storing the appimages on a usb drive to save space. The error output is bash: /media/chico/USB20FD/AppImages/Dolphin-23.08.1-x86-64.AppImage: Permission denied
bash: exec: /media/chico/USB20FD/AppImages/Dolphin-23.08.1-x86-64.AppImage: cannot execute: Permission denied

Comment: Please don't post comments, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1504074/edit) your question instead to add additional important information, thanks.What kind of filesysytem is used on that usb drive? How ist the drive mounted? Please add the relevant line from `findmnt`.

Comment: Please [edit] with `mount` . If that drive is mounted `noexec`, changing the permissions won't work without remounting

Comment: Please show the mount flags from `cat /proc/mounts`

Comment: @DanielT I doubt that permissions work at all with an "msdos" filesystem, whatever that is (likely FAT, but who knows)...

Comment: So your permission are fine based on your last edit. It seems that `gio set $1 metadata::trusted` requires an ext4 filesystem to hold that "extended attribute" but you have vfat

Comment: @mook765 is there a way to change the filesytem type to one that would work with my system?

Comment: The usb drive is now ext4 and working as expected. A big thanks to @DanielT and mook765!! If you could post your solution of needing to be in ext4 format I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that somehow [saving the gvfs attribute `gio set $1 metadata::trusted true` to `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1202488/1004020) wasn't working. The simple solution that worked was to backup and reformat as ext4. Thanks @mook765 for the hint about filesystem types.

The vfat filesystem was preinstalled on the drive, and since it was discovered that it is not used with Windows, the simplest way was to reformat as ext4. The problem was not with the `chmod` because the fmask and dmask were set properly. Somehow it wasn't about extended filesystem attributes but gvfs still didn't like the vfat for some reason, but using the more common ext4 worked around any remaining bugs.